# Any 36.4mm Dropper Seatposts?

Tags: seatpost

I've a diameter of 36.4mm, are there any dropper seat posts that make the size diameter for my bike?

Comment: Probably only option is a shim. A few questions on this site regarding the wisdom of using one.

Comment: Alright, Thank you very much, i didn't think of that. :)

Comment: Hm. Is 36.4 mm the internal diameter? There are a lot of bikes with 36.4 mm external diameter seatposts but 31.6 mm internal diameter (which supports a lot of dropper seatposts). You should use calipers or a seat measuring tool to measure the internal diameter if you're not sure.